# Inflation Option Modelling Approaches

Tags: inflation, stochastic, modelling

I am trying to come up with a simplistic inflation option model to get a sense of the materiality of some inflation-indexed contracts containing inflation guarantees. I have a stochastic nominal IR model (G2++) and I would like to tie my inflation scenarios to this model. My initial idea: Set up a short rate model to independently model Real IR such as the Ho-Lee model and calibrate it Real ZCB Discount Factors. Then, I could specify a correlation to tie the real and nominal IR models. However, I don't think this approach is feasible since CAN/US Real IR data often isn't available for short tenors. Does anybody have any alternative approaches for valuing inflation options ? I know there are complicated models such as the Jarrow-Yildrim model, but I want to keep my model as simple as possible and I would like to tie it to my Nominal IR model. Given my constraints, any suggestions for alternative modelling approaches ? Any resources would be greatly appreciated as well. Cheers!

Comment: Check out the Dodgson and Kainth model from RBS.